# Grab the first entry from json

Tags: python

I apologize ahead im really bad at explaining things.

I have a variable with json data in it, the first entry in this json data will change but i need too be able too call the first entry similar too how dictionairys work with dictionairy[0]. Is this possible?

Comment: The question isn't clear (at least for me). Please add an example of your data. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details.

Answer (score 0):

if that what you mean:

```
>>> example = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> first_key = list(example.keys())[0]
>>> example[first_key]
1
```